# not able to run python script on cron

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I am able to run the script using the command -  "/opt/conda/bin/python3 /home/jupyter/cron_files/cron1.py" but when I put on cron "29 15 * * * /opt/conda/bin/python3 /home/jupyter/cron_files/cron1.py" it does not run the script, any idea why this may be happening?

I am not sure if there is some permission error or I am missing some step

Comment: Maybe something along those lines of the path for your cron environment, perhaps? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38360425/8508004) for more about that. The comments below the OP there has some good trouble-shooting suggestions, too.